# Как со своей камеры передать изображение в другое приложение?

Tags: java, android, камера, android-intent

Как передать фото например в вк?
делаю так:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // сохраняем полученные jpg в папке /sdcard/CameraExample/
    // имя файла - System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (intent.getAction().equals (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)) {
        pictureData = data;
        sendPhoto();
    }
    else {
        ValuesMeCam.photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        camera.startPreview();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ChangePhotoApp.class));
    }


}

void sendPhoto(){



    try {
       Uri tmp =  savePhotoInFile (pictureData); //2
        intent.putExtra("data", pictureData); //3
        intent.setData(tmp);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        setResult(2, intent); //4
    }
    camera.release();
    finish();
}

private Uri savePhotoInFile(byte[] data) throws Exception {
    File newDir = null;
    try
    {
        File pictures = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        File saveDir = new File(pictures.getAbsolutePath() + "/meCamera/");

        if (!saveDir.exists())
        {
            saveDir.mkdirs();
        }
        int time = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        newDir = new File(saveDir.getAbsolutePath() + time + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(String.format(saveDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + time + ".jpg"));
        Bitmap tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        tmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
        os.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return Uri.fromFile(newDir);
}
```

но приложение просто зависает.

Comment: Добавил camera.startPreview(); после sendPhoto(); теперь не зависает, но фото не подхватывает

Comment: Если камера выдаёт вам битмап, то вы можете посмотреть как его отправить интентом в ответе по ссылке выше.